# I want to modify this bash script to not ask for password for each file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

I want to modify this bash script to not ask for password for each file but look for password in the following file /home/user/Documents/pass.txt

I got this nice script on GIT hub and it works but it prompts me for passphrase for each file I want to encrypt, I would like to modify the script to seek password from a text file in /home/user/Documents/pass.txt and read the password in the pass.txt file and encrypt all files in the directory using siad password

Please Help I have been doing this manually for the past 2 weeks

```
#!/bin/bash

# This uses gpg to encrypt every file in a directory as separate
# encrypted files

# Usage
# ./encrypt-all.sh ./dir-of-files-to-encrypt "PASSPHRASE"

FILES="$1"
PASSPHRASE="$2"

pushd $FILES

for file_name in ./*; do
  enc_name="$file_name.gpg"

  echo "Encrypting $file_name"

  gpg \
    --passphrase "$PASSPHRASE" \
    --batch \
    --output "$file_name.gpg" \
    --symmetric \
    --cipher-algo AES256 \
    "$file_name"

  echo "Done! Output: $gpg_name"
done

popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `--passphrase-file` instead of `--passphrase`, to indicate the name of the file whose first line is the passphrase to use.